# Stop UIView from going off screen

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView that is a circle. That is all the app is - I can move the circle around the screen using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer.` Now I don't want my circle to be able to be dragged off screen. For example, if I drag the circle to the right, it should stop moving the circle when the right edge hits the edge of the window.

Here is my code:

```
 switch rec.state {
        case .Began:
            x = fingerLocation.x - (myView?.center.x)!
            y = fingerLocation.y - (myView?.center.y)!
            break


        case .Changed:
            myView?.center.x = fingerLocation.x - x
            myView?.center.y = fingerLocation.y - y

            if (myView?.center.x)! + (myView!.bounds.width/2) >= view.bounds.width {
                myView?.center.x = view.bounds.width - myView!.bounds.width/2
            }
            break
        case .Ended:
            myView?.center = CGPointMake(fingerLocation.x - x, fingerLocation.y - y)
            break
}
```

This code works if I drag the circle slowly toward the edge. If I drag quickly, the circle will go over the edge, and jump back into view the second another `.Changed` state is sent. **How can I stop the circle from ever going over the edge?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check *first* if the fingerLocation would result in an offscreen view,
and move the view only if it would not move offscreen.

```
case .Changed: 
   let currentRightEdge = CGRectGetMaxX(myView!.frame)
   let potentialRightEdge = currentRightEdge + fingerLocation.x - x
   if  potentialRightEdge >= view.bounds.width {
     myView?.center.x = view.bounds.width - myView!.bounds.width/2
   }
   else {
     myView?.center.x = potentialRightEdge
   }
   myView?.center.y = fingerLocation.y - y
```

Also, I do not think you need the `break` in Swift ;-).

Comment: Could you maybe post some pseudocode? I have been at it for a couple hours with little progress.

Comment: Thanks! How can you use x without knowing what it is though?

Comment: Something like the code I added to my answer. Can be abbreviated, I made it more verbose for clarity.

Comment: You introduced the x in your code without explaining what it is or how you calculate it. I assumed you know how to calculate the new position using this variable. Maybe you should add it to your question to clarify.

Comment: That's what I thought. Perhaps the shortest class-wide variable I have ever seen ;-). So it is set in `.Began`, that should work, right?

Comment: Oh no there is a bug in your solution! When `.Changed` runs, the circle jumps to the right edge and stays there until `.Ended`.

Comment: You are in a better position to step through the code and examine the values. I am sure you can find out the bug. Please let us know so I can correct it. Perhaps you have to change `x` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that if the view goes offscreen, you set the `myView?.center.x` twice. Try this:

```
case .Changed:
            myView?.center.y = fingerLocation.y - y
            var newX : Int = fingerLocation.x - x

            if (newX + (myView!.bounds.width/2)) >= view.bounds.width {
                myView?.center.x = view.bounds.width - myView!.bounds.width/2
            } else {
                myView?.center.x = newX
            }
            break
```

Comment: Would you like to see what `x` and `y` are? There are where on the circle the user taps. `x = fingerLocation.x - (myView?.center.x)!
            y = fingerLocation.y - (myView?.center.y)!`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
case .Changed:
    var targetX = fingerLocation.x - x
    if targetX < 0 {
        targetX = 0
    } else if targetX > CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds) {
        targetX = CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds)
    }

    var targetY = fingerLocation.y - y
    if targetY < 0 {
        targetY = 0
    } else if targetY > CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) {
        targetY = CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds)
    }

    myView?.center = CGPoint(x: targetX, y: targetY)
```